# Unknown Error P12 File for Moon APNS

Tags: c#, ssl, apple-push-notifications, moonapns

Does anyone of you know how to generate p12 file for MoonAPNS? For information, i have 2 different projects. At first i've tried to generated the file p12 for my first project and the push notification mechanism was going well, but when i tried to do the same things for my second project (absolutely with different AppID and different p12 file), i got a rejected sign. Was I missing a step ?

[image: Screenshot of Rejection]

FYI : I was following this URL's steps 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/

Comment: Please show your code as a text, not as an image..

Comment: I think that the code goes well, because i've already tried to run the following code with my previous p12, and it was running well. But when  i regenerate the p12 file, the nightmare had just started :(

Answer (score 0):

As you said you have two different projects, I understand that they are two different apps. For each AppID you should create a APNS certificate of development or production and then follow the steps in this link you posted. For each APP, it generates a token device at the time the application will perform the push registry on the iphone, you would not be spending a device token generated in the push registry of another app? If this is the case just pick up the device token generated by the app and use the correct p12 generated certificate to send pushs for those who have this app.